# Unable to connect to MongoDB databases running on custom ports in Docker Compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have set up two MongoDB databases using Docker Compose, and they are running on custom ports (:27310, :27311). My Node.js application is able to connect to these databases successfully, both when running on my desktop and within the Docker Compose environment. However, I am experiencing issues connecting to these databases using MongoDB Compass or other UI tools. Whenever I try to connect, I receive a "connection refused" error(connect ECONNREFUSED).

Here is the relevant part of my Docker Compose configuration for the MongoDB containers:

```
  app-mongo-db:
    container_name: app-mongo-db
    image: mongo:6.0.6
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]
    ports:
      - "27310:27017"
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - mongo-app-data:/data/db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network

  feed-mongo-db:
    container_name: feed-mongo-db
    image: mongo:6.0.6
    command: ["--replSet", "rs1", "--bind_ip_all"]
    ports:
      - "27311:27017"
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - mongo-feed-data:/data/db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Interestingly, when I modify the Docker Compose configuration to use the default MongoDB port (27017), everything works well. The databases are accessible from MongoDB Compass without any issues.

Is there anything I am missing in my configuration or any additional steps I need to take to allow connections to the MongoDB databases from MongoDB Compass? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Port publishing only impacts access from the host. When connecting from another container, you connect to the port on which the application is actually listening.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. Yeah, I understand that. But Nodejs app run on the host machine is able to connect to the Mongo via localhost:27311, but Mongo Compas - doesn't, it's the point